# Copy a file with spaces and curly quotes

Tags: windows, cmd

I have the file name: xxx ,a b".pdf

I need to copy it using the command line. I have tried the commands but none of them work

```
copy "xxx ,a b".pdf" folder => xxx ,a b.pdf
copy "xxx ,a b"".pdf" folder => error the file can not be found
copy "xxx ,a b""".pdf" folder => xxx ,a b.pdf
copy "xxx ,a b^".pdf" folder =>xxx ,a b^.pdf
copy "xxx ,a b%".pdf" folder =>xxx ,a b%.pdf
copy "xxx ,a b~".pdf" folder =>xxx ,a b~.pdf
```

Can this be done? I should mention that the filename comes as a parameter.

UPDATE indead is not english double quote is another type of special quotes xxx „a b“. In my defense in the command when I run dir command it looked like double quote. So with dir the starting quote looks like a comma and the end quote looks like double quotes

Comment: A file can't contain " in it's name - otherwise enclosing in quotes should suffice for spaces

Comment: The command interpreter removes quotes in paths, but in file names they are forbidden…

Comment: As already obvious from the above responses, the question is irrelevant because a Windows filename, _(a directory is technically a file too)_, cannot contain a doublequote, because it is an invalid character, as are `\ `, `/`, `:`, `*`, `?`, `>`, `<` and `|`. As you're telling us that the filename is coming as a parameter, it looks as if your parameter has been created incorrectly in the first instance, and is what you should be dealing with. My guess is that you're joining two doublequoted variables/strings, instead of joining them without doublequotes, then enclosing the result with them.

Comment: If it can not contain how come I have a file with the double quote in it? Maybe is not really double quote is a character that looks like double quote.

Comment: The simple answer is that because it cannot contain one, it does not contain one. You're probably looking at smart/curly quotes, `“`, and `”`, not dumb/straight quotes, `"`, and `"`.

Comment: You can turn off filename checks by prepending the name with ` \\?\ ` but parsers will preprocess. If you are using OEM it is probably converted to a double quote. Try using Unicode `chcp 65001`.

Comment: I tried chcp 65001 and the dir command could no longer display the filename. Also the prepending did not help either